# What are changes made to a database schema that is already in 4NF that would break applications?

Tags: normalization

For this question I consider applications select and use columns by name (so I am excluding use of `select *` as a breaking change).

Asked in a different way, is it the case that once a Database schema is in 4NF then any change that **needs** to be applied to it should only be an "additive" change and therefore not break any existing applications that use it?

For me I am discounting some obvious changes:

- Drop column (This change can be held back and only applied once all uses of the column are no longer active)
- Drop table (Same as drop column)

For me I am considering "additive" changes as non-breaking:

- Add column
- Add table
- Denormalisation (Add column + whatever triggers etc are required)

For me the "Refactoring" change that would break applications is to alter a columns datatype (e.g. Change from INTEGER to VARCHAR type)

What other changes can be made to a schema in 4NF that will break applications using that schema?

**UPDATE:** Currently we have:

- Changing the data type in a breaking way (INTEGER -> VARCHAR)
- Adding a constraint (or tightening an existing constraint)

**Q:** Are there any schema design changes that can take a design from 4NF into a different 4NF design?

Comment: I'm guessing this question is a hypothetical or thought experiment, as it doesn't seem to have much of a real world bent to it. I guess it could also be a job interview question to see if people understood normalization or theory.  I'm trying to understand the useful, real-life situation where this question has any meaning other than what I have guessed here.  So learning is good, but that's not what Stack is supposed to be used for.

Comment: @Karen Lopez Yes you could say it is a thought experiment specifically related to the push towards "microservices" in software development (and how that pertains to Database design). My thought is there is significant push (from "microservices" architecture) towards totally independent databases for each microservice. This can have significant negative impact on  database design / loss of constraints etc.

Comment: I might be re-writing history a bit here but back 20 years ago (client server days for me) Database designers were a significant part of the development team and databases were 'designed' with a relatively holistic enterprise view.  Fast forward and it seems to me that Database designers are not as involved for some reason.  It might be just my experiences but DB Designers and DBA's are often not prominent when "interesting" architectural decisions are made.

Comment: As I see it many "software architects" pushing for "microservices architecture" do not have faith in 4NF. Their solution is to abstract away from the database schema (absolutely no matter the cost).  This can have pretty major implications.  My thought is that for some reason over the last 20 years development teams have "lost faith in 4NF" and my question is if that is valid (because I've seen fairly large $$ go to what I think bad architectural decisions).

Comment: For software developers **everything** is changeable in a **breaking fashion**. To mitigate this the answer is to define an abstract interface (to enable the implementation can change without breaking the caller etc). The concept that a non-abstract design (DB schema where all the tables are in 4NF) can be relied upon by an application to not change in a **breaking fashion** is a large conceptual leap for some "software architects"

Comment: I've gone into architectural meetings batting for the side that says **It is safe to depend on database schemas where all the tables are in 4NF**.  I've done that because I've seen huge waste when "microservices architecture" wins with polygot persistence, lack of data integrity and a myriad of other costs.  I want to know if I have missed something ... because I feel these are fairly important decisions to understand fully (well, as best I can).

Comment: For those interested - a related "microservice architecture" question regard read only access to a database schema: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/263735/why-is-it-so-bad-to-read-data-from-a-database-owned-by-a-different-microservic

Answer (score 2):

Most changes are "breaking" if you aren't careful.  Any change to code for example (you mentioned triggers).  Any new or modified constraints, calculated columns etc.

You could even add a new index and effectively "break" your application because a query that used to run sub second now runs in seconds, minutes, even hours because the query plan has changed.

Assuming your code is written to always specifically name columns will probably make adding new columns reasonably safe and adding a table almost always is but you still probably want to test how each change to your database affects your application and it's performance.

Comment: Thanks. I am looking for specific changes to the **logical model** that will **stop an application from working** . What that means is that "Adding columns (derived or not)" I don't consider a breaking change. Similarly I do not consider adding an index a breaking change. Similarly when we say "Add a trigger" why would that break an application - I wouldn't expect that to be the case so can you give an example for that?

Comment: Ultimately I'm looking to answer the question of what cases a schema can go from 4NF to a another different 4NF schema? (because I don't think it can by definition of Normalization/4NF).  **UPDATE:** It might be best to ask that question explicitly as a separate question.

Comment: Example of adding a trigger that can cause an application to break : A trigger with a bug, a trigger that takes a long time, etc.  Note: The change of normalization really doesn't affect an application one way or the other.

Comment: Again I'm excluding performance so that excludes "a trigger that takes time". That leaves us with "A trigger with a bug".

Comment: `Note: The change of normalization really doesn't affect an application one way or the other.`  Can you elaborate what you mean by that?  Going from 3NF to 4NF I'd expect to break an application - we want to get to 4NF for a reason and specifically the only changes from there **SHOULD** be denormalization (or 5NF).  So no I do not understand your comment there.

Comment: In general a database does not have a `normal form`.  Tables do.  So you could have one table that's 3NF and another that's 5th.  The normal form (within reason) won't make or break an application.  The code (both database and not) will break (or not) your application.  And a common mistake is to forget performance. It may not seem to cause a direct error but if a query takes 5 minutes and your timeout is 30 seconds you'll get an error.

Comment: Some background: I've been trained in Normalisation. I worked for Oracle (fully qualified Oracle DBA). Over the last 25 years I've worked with quite a few large DB designs and designed rather large ones myself. I've written an ORM that generates DDL for 5 different databases include SQL2011 History support for Postgres and MySql.  So yes, I know what normalisation is. My question states that the starting point is 4NF (not 3NF).

Comment: `And a common mistake is to forget performance.` This question is is trying to identify what **logical changes** have people made in the past to a schema that is already in **4NF** that stop an application from working.  The joy of the physical/logical separation is that it allows us to separate those considerations.

Comment: If someone didn't get an OLTP database design to 4NF (they only got to 3NF say) then yes - changing the design from 3NF to 4NF is going to break applications using that schema (which is why we **want** to get to 4NF right, and then denormalise from there as needed).

Comment: I'm confused.  You are treating normalization like a goal or grade. It is not. It is a measure.  A table with one key and one non-key column could have a very high normal form.  It's not a contest to "get to xNF".

Schemas don't have normalization levels.  Relations (tables) do.  Since normalization is based on meaning and the key, only relations have normal levels.

Comment: It is possibly my different semantics where I'd say `Normalisation` is the process by which you takes table designs from 1NF to 2NF to 3NF to 4NF. For me I'd say 1NF, 2NF ... is a level of normalisation.

Comment: `It's not a contest to "get to xNF".`  Well for me doing a database design absolutely yes I want to get to 4NF (and then denormalise as needed after that).  When I say schema I'm meaning all the tables in a schema. If you are doing a database design do you not aim to get to 4NF?

Comment: @Karen Lopez  Ok, I think I get what you are saying. A particular table might be in 3NF but there is no higher normal form for that particular table to obtain.  What I'm saying is kind of confusing in that way ... more accurately I should say `All tables are at each at their highest normalisation up to 4NF` ... or `there are no tables at 2NF, 3NF etc that should be at a higher level`.   That would be a better way of saying it I think.